# sort orders in nonalphabetic order with = followed by a string

Tags: gnu-coreutils

Why does sort order in a different order when = followed by a string is appended to a line? Is this the correct behaviour or a bug in my version?

```
$ echo -e "a  = T\nab = T"|sort
ab = T
a  = T
$ echo -e "a  = \nab = "|sort
a  = 
ab =
$  sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13
```

To me this seems to happen if there are two lines where one starts with a word which is a substring of the first word in the other line.

Answer (score 0):

It's your locale ignoring spaces. Try:

```
echo -e "a  = T\nab = T" | LC_ALL=C sort
```

or restrict to the first field

```
echo -e "a  = T\nab = T" | sort -k1,1
```